# how to fix unexpected error?

Tags: java, arraylist, return, return-value

Alright, so what I want it to do is return true if the server is functioning normally, or an ArrayList of servers not functioning properly. Otherwise, it returns false.

The problem is I get the error stated in the subject. Here is my code.

```
public ArrayList<Server> needsAttention() 
{ 

for (int i = 0; i < Server.length()-1; i++) {
    if( currentServer.ping()==false) {
        failedServersList+=currentServer;
    }
    return failedServers;
}
```

Comment: `add currentServer to failedServersList` is invalid syntax in most of the languages I know of.

Comment: How come you expect `add currentServer to failedServersList;` to be a valid statement?

Comment: Also, which language is this? Could be either C++ or Java.

Comment: How do you add currentserver to failedServersList?Code please.

Comment: @user, re: your edit, `failedServersList+=currentServer` probably won't work either.

Comment: Java. Thx, I caught the "failed server" mistake, but I got another error "cannot find symbol."

Comment: Should I have another for-loop that for each failed server in current servers, it returns that server? I mean, like add it to a separate array and return that array.

Comment: @user2932: When you edit, please make sure to do in a way that can be retraced. Now your question title doesn't match your code any more, and to top it off you now have a completely new question.

Comment: Also, please do not give us any details. It really doesn't matter which symbol your compiler is complaining about… and don't give us any informations about these symbols, we like guessing what you're doing. Geez…

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error comes because you didn't close your function properly

```
    public ArrayList<Server> needsAttention() { 

      for (int i = 0; i < Server.length()-1; i++) {
          if( currentServer.ping()==false) {
              failedServersList+=currentServer;
          }
          return failedServers;
      }
      return something;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing in Java, as the tag suggests, you should add elements to the ArrayList using the add method. Look into the [official API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29)